# How to install libCVD on windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, lnk2019

I use windows 8 64 bit. I try to install [libCVD](https://github.com/edrosten/libcvd) . I run `./configure;make; make install;` commands on cygwin terminal. The screenshot is below :

[image]
I create a c++ project on vs2013. Then I add `/usr/local/bin` to environment setting->Path. I add `/usr/local/include` to `c++ project->Properties -> c++ -> Additional Include Library`. I add `usr/local/lib` to `c++ project->Properties ->Linker-> Additional Library Directory`. I add name of files under `/usr/local/lib` to `usr/local/lib` to `c++ project->Properties ->Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependency`.

I build c++ project on vs2013 it throws  `Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CVD::Internal::aligned_free(void *)" (?aligned_free@Internal@CVD@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl CVD::Internal::aligned_free<unsigned char>(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (??$aligned_free@E@Internal@CVD@@YAXPAEI@Z)`

How can I add `x.dll.a` files to vs project?

Comment: ***How can I add x.dll.a files to vs project?*** You can not use the .a file in Visual Studio.

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls

Comment: I don't have any .lib files to linking.